# Fix Crease Where Two Objects Meet

Tags: objects, shaders, lighting, shadows, artifacts

[image: Odd Shadows Where Objects Meet]

**Goal:** To get the two objects (mountain and flat plane) to have a seamless transition while still keeping them as separate objects.

**What I've Done:** I made it so that the mountain texture fades to the texture that I used on the plane. I tried sculpting the plane to get it to slope up to the mountain.

Any advice would be much appreciated!! I am not opposed to going at this from a completely different angle, I just would prefer to keep the two as separate objects.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the texture transition smoothly from the mountain to the ground like in the answer by @moonboots or are you asking how to get the mesh of the terrain to smoothly transition from mountain to ground plane?

Comment: I realize now that the problem is mostly from the fact that there is not a smooth transition between the two meshes. I'm not sure of a great way to achieve that, but if you have any ideas I would really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create one unique material for both the ground and the mountain, mix the 2 *Principled BSDF* (one for the ground, one for the mountain shader) into a *Mix Shader* and use an *Image Texture* as factor. For the moment the *Image Texture* is completely black so it only show the mountain shader:

[image]

Then paint the *Image Texture* in white in order to reveal the ground shader. Of course you can use an image as Texture to have a more subtle painting:

[image]

The ground and the mountain can even remain 2 different objects that share the same material:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I am actually currently doing something very similar with vertex painting as opposed to using an image texture. I'm not sure if that makes a large difference. @GordonBrinkman made a good point: I think my actual problem comes from not being able to smoothly transition between the two meshes.